# Fixity declarations for data constructors

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to declare fixity for a data constructor in Haskell. For instance, given:

```
data A = (>>>) A A
```

I would like to declare

```
infixl 4 >>>
```

Looking at [the data type extensions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html) documentation it seems one can only declare fixity for the type constructor. But even that does not seem to work, at least in the way I tried:

```
infixl 7 A
data A = (>>>) A A
```

Can this be done at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this allright, just, infix constructors must always begin with a colon.

```
infixl 7 :>>>
data A = A :>>> A
```

Comment: Right! I forgot about that :/